# kickstart commerce 2 in openshift /admin/modules/list/confirm with no response (white dead screen)

Tags: drupal, memory-management, buffer, openshift, commerce

I installed commerce kickstart on openshift. I had /admin/modules/list/confirm return white screen. Look like the execution cannot be finished. On my local system (aquria drupal desktop in PC), there is no this kind of situation. Do I need to enable some buffer or locate more resource for the app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know first what error is being thrown that causes the white dead screen. To be able to do so, you will need to add the following lines to your drupal site's `index.php` file.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Then visit the page that causes the white screen, you will see the error message.

Comment: Thank you. The error was memory size of 16777216 bytes exhausted ... After I add ini_set('memory_limit', '256M'); to settings.php. It works well.